# Unable to map page in DispatcherServlet in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC4</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

`Controller1.java` defined inside com.test

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/met")
public class Controller1 {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("operation", name);
        return "met";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDefault(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("operation", "Please enter an operation");
        return "met";
    }

}
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC4/met

I get error

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC4/met] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

Comment: And when you try `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC4/met/`?

Comment: what is the Name of your `war` file?

Comment: @Jens: SpringMVC4.war

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC4/met/xyz is working or not? @user544079

Comment: I get above mentioned error  at http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC4/met/xyz          "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC4/met] in DispatcherServlet with name HelloWeb"

Comment: Turn logging for `org.springframework.web` to DEBUG and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add < mvc:annotation-driven /> in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml.
Maybe it will helpful.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```